# Myers Levenshtein in Java from C (Java unsigned bit manipulation)

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation, levenshtein-distance

I'm attempting to use the Myers bit-parallel algorithm to perform fast approximate string matching in Java. I found an excellent implementation in C, but am having issues with implementing it in Java. My version never seems to update the score variable.

Below is the C implementation: (credit goes to [Fujimoto Seiji](https://ceptord.net/20200815-Comparison.html))

```c
int8_t myers1999(char *s1, int8_t len1, char *s2, int8_t len2) {
    // In the benchmarks, len1 and len2 are the same number (I assume this is k)
    uint64_t Peq[256]; 
    uint64_t Eq, Xv, Xh, Ph, Mh, Pv, Mv, Last;
    int8_t i;
    int8_t Score = len2;

    memset(Peq, 0, sizeof(Peq));

    for (i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        Peq[s2[i]] |= (uint64_t) 1 << i;

    Mv = 0;
    Pv = (uint64_t) -1;
    Last = (uint64_t) 1 << (len2 - 1);
    printf("Last: %lu\n", Last);
    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        Eq = Peq[s1[i]];

        Xv = Eq | Mv;
        Xh = (((Eq & Pv) + Pv) ^ Pv) | Eq;

        Ph = Mv | ~ (Xh | Pv);
        Mh = Pv & Xh;

        printf("Eq: %lu\n", Eq);
        printf("Xv: %lu\n", Xv);
        printf("Xh: %lu\n", Xh);
        printf("Ph: %lu\n", Ph);
        printf("Mh: %lu\n", Mh);
        printf("Pv: %lu\n", Pv);
        printf("Mv: %lu\n", Mv);
        printf("\n");

        if (Ph & Last) Score++;
        if (Mh & Last) Score--;

        Ph = (Ph << 1) | 1;
        Mh = (Mh << 1);

        Pv = Mh | ~ (Xv | Ph);
        Mv = Ph & Xv;
     }
     return Score;
}
```

Now follows my version in Java:

```java
private int myers(String s1, String s2, int k) {

    final long[] charIndex = new long[256];
    long eq, xv, xh, ph, mh, pv, mv, last;
    int i;
    int score = k;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        charIndex[s2.charAt(i)] |= 1L << i;
    }

    mv = 0;
    pv = 0xFFFFffffFFFFffffL;
    last = 1L << (k - 1);
    System.out.println("Last: "+Long.toUnsignedString(last));
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        eq = charIndex[s1.charAt(i)];

        xv = eq | mv;
        xh = (((eq & pv) + pv) ^ pv) | eq;

        ph = mv | (~(xh | pv) & 0xff); // unsigned complement
        mh = pv & xh;

        System.out.println("Eq: "+Long.toUnsignedString(eq));
        System.out.println("Xv: "+Long.toUnsignedString(xv));
        System.out.println("Xh: "+Long.toUnsignedString(xh));
        System.out.println("Ph: "+Long.toUnsignedString(ph));
        System.out.println("Mh: "+Long.toUnsignedString(mh));
        System.out.println("Pv: "+Long.toUnsignedString(pv));
        System.out.println("Mv: "+Long.toUnsignedString(mv));
        System.out.println();

        if ((ph & last) != 0) score++; // score is almost never updated
        if ((mh & last) != 0) score--;

        ph = (ph << 1) | 1;
        mh = (mh << 1);

        pv = mh | (~(xv | ph) & 0xff); // unsigned complement
        mv = ph & xv;
    }

    return score;
}
```

As far as I am aware, only the ~ operator is different for unsigned numbers. I am missing something with the overflow in bit manipulation? Can anyone help me with finding what is wrong?

P.S. I wish I could add the tag 'Myers' to give this question proper context, but I cannot.

**Edit**
As Federico suggested, I added some console output to both programs. They are indeed different. Below is the output:

First the main method in c:

```c
int main()
{
    
    char test1[] = "ABCDFGEGA";
    char test2[] = "BCDEFGEGA";
    int8_t k = 7;
    int8_t result1 = myers1999(test1, k, test2, k);
    printf("%i\n", result1);
    return 0;
}
```

The Java code I won't add, it is equivalent to this (same strings, etc...)

C output:

```yaml
Last: 64
Eq: 0
Xv: 0
Xh: 0
Ph: 0
Mh: 0
Pv: 18446744073709551615
Mv: 0

Eq: 1
Xv: 1
Xh: 1
Ph: 0
Mh: 0
Pv: 18446744073709551614
Mv: 0

Eq: 2
Xv: 3
Xh: 18446744073709551614
Ph: 1
Mh: 18446744073709551614
Pv: 18446744073709551614
Mv: 1

Eq: 4
Xv: 7
Xh: 18446744073709551612
Ph: 3
Mh: 18446744073709551612
Pv: 18446744073709551612
Mv: 3

Eq: 16
Xv: 23
Xh: 18446744073709551600
Ph: 7
Mh: 18446744073709551600
Pv: 18446744073709551608
Mv: 7

Eq: 32
Xv: 39
Xh: 18446744073709551584
Ph: 31
Mh: 18446744073709551584
Pv: 18446744073709551584
Mv: 7

Eq: 72
Xv: 111
Xh: 18446744073709551560
Ph: 55
Mh: 18446744073709551552
Pv: 18446744073709551552
Mv: 39

2
```

Java output:

```yaml
Last: 64
Eq: 0
Xv: 0
Xh: 0
Ph: 0
Mh: 0
Pv: 18446744073709551615
Mv: 0

Eq: 1
Xv: 1
Xh: 1
Ph: 0
Mh: 0
Pv: 254
Mv: 0

Eq: 2
Xv: 3
Xh: 510
Ph: 1
Mh: 254
Pv: 254
Mv: 1

Eq: 4
Xv: 7
Xh: 1020
Ph: 3
Mh: 508
Pv: 508
Mv: 3

Eq: 16
Xv: 23
Xh: 2032
Ph: 7
Mh: 1008
Pv: 1016
Mv: 7

Eq: 32
Xv: 39
Xh: 4064
Ph: 31
Mh: 2016
Pv: 2016
Mv: 7

Eq: 72
Xv: 111
Xh: 8136
Ph: 55
Mh: 4032
Pv: 4032
Mv: 39

2.0
```

Comment: My C is a bit rusty, I don't know the specific algorithm and I'm not sure it matters, but isn't `uint64_t` 64-bits wide? Why did you use an `int` (32-bits wide) in the java version?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried using longs, but with the same result. At the end I (perhaps wrongly) thought it wouldn't matter.

Comment: By the way I would try to print intermediate results to at least pin down where the difference is.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for the suggestion, I added some console output to the code and got different results, I still don't get why they're different though. I will update the question with the console output.

Comment: In your code `pv = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // unsigned int = -1`. Well no. The C Code is setting all the bits to 1 by `(uint64_t) -1`. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` has the most significant digit set to 0.

Comment: The first difference in the output is the first `Pv:` value. `pv = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` (`0x7FFFffff`) is not an equivalent of `Pv = (uint64_t) -1;` (`0xFFFFffffFFFFffff`)

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I have updated the code to make use of longs and set the last variable to the correct value. I also updated the java code to print unsigned numbers. Console output was changed accordingly.

Comment: I have found the problems. One of the issues was indeed the initial value of Pv. The other was that, with the correct value for Pv, the complement could be as in the C code

Comment: To recapitulate: none of the operators used it this specific code depends on the signedness of the datatype. They all have well defined results (bit patterns) for all inputs. That also applies to the mentioned `~` operator. But also to the `+` operator, which not everyone is aware of. There is also no reason to use a different literal for the “all bits set” value; using `-1` works. Though, it would be more idiomatic to use `~0` for this purpose; this would avoid casting a signed value to an unsigned type in `C`. But keep in mind that a Java `char` is 16 bit wide which this code doesn’t handle.

Answer (score 0):

With the very helpful comments I have figured out what was wrong with my code. Below is a working Java version of the C code. If anyone ever needs it, I hope they find it here.

```java
    private int myers(String s1, String s2) {

        final int len1 = s1.length();
        final int len2 = s2.length();

        final long[] charIndex = new long[256];

        long eq, xv, xh, ph, mh, pv, mv, last;
        int i;
        int score = len2;

        for (i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
            charIndex[s2.charAt(i)] |= 1L << i;
        }

        mv = 0;
        pv = 0xFFFFffffFFFFffffL;
        last = 1L << (len2 - 1);

        for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
            eq = charIndex[s1.charAt(i)];

            xv = eq | mv;
            xh = (((eq & pv) + pv) ^ pv) | eq;

            ph = mv | ~(xh | pv);
            mh = pv & xh;

            if ((ph & last) != 0) score++;
            if ((mh & last) != 0) score--;

            ph = (ph << 1) | 1;
            mh = (mh << 1);

            pv = mh | ~(xv | ph);
            mv = ph & xv;
        }

        return score;
    }
```